# Animate over properties in UIView using draw in rect

Tags: swift, animation

I have my custom view like this :

```
@IBDesignable
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBInspectable var cardColor : UIColor = UIColor.white
@IBInspectable var cardHorizontalPadding : Int = 20
@IBInspectable var cardVerticalPadding : Int = 20
@IBInspectable var cardCornerRadius : Int = 10
@IBInspectable var cardShadowRadius : Int = 6

var cardLayer : CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
var cardRect = CGRect.zero;

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    print("Sublayers count is \(layer.sublayers?.count)")
    let cardRect = rect.insetBy(dx: CGFloat(self.cardHorizontalPadding), dy: CGFloat(self.cardVerticalPadding))
    let cardPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cardRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat(self.cardCornerRadius)).cgPath

    cardLayer.lineWidth = 0
    cardLayer.fillColor = self.cardColor.cgColor

    cardLayer.path = cardPath
    cardLayer.shadowRadius = CGFloat(self.cardShadowRadius)
    cardLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: -0.2, height: -0.2)
    cardLayer.shadowPath = cardPath
    cardLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    layer.addSublayer(cardLayer)
    layer.replaceSublayer(cardLayer, with: cardLayer)



}



override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {


    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

And I want to animate over `cardVerticalPadding`, like this

```
UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 1/10, animations: {

                currentCell.cardVerticalPadding = 10
            })
```

and it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`UIView` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview):

> The following properties of the UIView class are animatable:
>
> - frame
> - bounds
> - center
> - transform
> - alpha
> - backgroundColor

So the reason is that the `UIKit` animation framework is quite limited in the properties that it can manage. The solution is to manage your own animations using `CADisplayLink` to update your properties each time the display is refreshed. I've written a framework to make this super easy, it's available here: https://github.com/j-h-a/Animation (using the very permissive MIT License). Also available with [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/), just add `pod 'Animation'` to your `Podfile`.

The API is a bit different than the `UIKit` animations, instead of setting the final value, your closure gets called repeatedly and you set whatever value you want at the time, based on a `progress` value that's passed in. Here is an example usage for your case:

```
import Animation

...

Animation.animate(identifier: "animateVerticalPadding", duration: 0.1,
    update: { progress in
        currentCell.cardVerticalPadding = 20.0 <~~ progress ~~> 10.0
    })
```

The `<~~` and `~~>` operators is my syntax for linear interpolation, that is equivalent to `lerp(20.0, 10.0, progress)`. `20.0` is the initial value, `10.0` is the final value. If you wanted to use an ease-in-ease-out curve instead of linear, then you can do this:

```
currentCell.cardVerticalPadding = 20.0 <~~ Curve.easeInEaseOut[progress] ~~> 10.0
```

Alternatively, you can calculate the current value using whatever means you prefer, using `progress` (which increases from `0.0` to `1.0` over the duration) to calculate the current value you want. The interpolation and curves are just helpers.